# Flattening annotations from Preview without rasterizing existing text

Tags: macos, pdf, ocr

I'm trying to flatten annotations I make to PDF files in macOS Preview (El Capitan) to ensure that they cannot be modified. I especially want to ensure that redactions cannot be deleted or unhidden to reveal the text beneath. Ideally, I would also like to preserve the machine-readability and vector quality of the text.

Currently, I achieve this by exporting to .tif, then converting back to .pdf, and then OCR'ing with Abbyy FineReader Express. That's a bit ridiculous, but the final result is almost exactly what I want: permanent annotations and searchable/copyable text. It loses some quality though... and grows in size.

I'm comfortable with the CLI and I've got MacPorts installed and pdftk. I hoped that the pdftk "flatten" option would do the trick, but it does not. It only seems to flatten form fields.

Does anything else out there do this? I swear there was a way to do this on some old built-in imaging program for Windows 2000 or something. (but I'm ok not going back to that)  :-)

I would settle for a command that rasterizes the file if and only if it:

1. did everything in one step
2. kept the file small
3. kept the file as a pdf
4. kept the file as almost as readable and pretty as it was before

Comment: Are you only looking for existing tool or would hints towards libraries with which you can create such a tool help, too?

Answer (score 0):

The "Best Practice" for Redactions in PDF is to either use Acrobat's Redaction tool, or the (long time industry leader) Redax Acrobat plug-in for Acrobat (although that one is not made for MacOS, as far as I remember).

Of course, the export as picture and then run OCR over it does work, but you have to absolutely make sure that you also clean up the file(s) from any private data and metadata.

Note that with the "real" redaction tools, you have the possibility for smart searches, even involving Regular Expressions.

With Redaction, as with other safety and security-related issues, it is up to you to decide how much it is worth to you.

Comment: OK. That's definitely good to know. But what about locking in text that has been added? And signatures and notes?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Export as PDF" (in the File Menu) which seems definitely a proper way to do it (on 10.9.5).

It seemed that the way to make these annotations permanent is [printing to PDF with Preview](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5163504?tstart=0), but that didn't succeed.

Comment: It might not satisfy OPs strict requirements, but exporting the PDF makes annotations etc not editable anymore.